# how do i configure my ember brunch application for testing with testacular/karma?

Tags: ember.js, karma-runner, brunch

i've been using brunch with ember https://github.com/fuseelements/ember-brunch-skeleton

and now i'm trying to get unit tests happening with testacular/karma (testacular recently was renamed to karma)

brunch uses require.js.  when i try to run karma, i get an error which leads me to believe either require isn't loaded properly, or my config file is messed up.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object function (deps, callback, errback, optional) { 
 ..... has no method 'register' at app.js:82
```

i'm assuming my config file is messed up, or i'm forgetting something really simple here.  here's the relevant snippet from my karma config file.  what am i doing wrong?

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  REQUIRE,
  REQUIRE_ADAPTER,  
  '../public/javascripts/app_vendor.js',
  '../public/javascripts/app.js',
  'test/**/**/*_spec.js',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but you should go read the **new** doc about running unit tests of an app built using ember with Karma there: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-runners/#toc_the-karma-test-runner

Also any test method has been dropped out from `brunch`, which can only build files for you. I used to use `karma` with `brunch` with success and now moved over `testem` with success too.

You should look into this skeleton which is using `karma` as test runner for an exemple: https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded